# Can a rear end collision cause damage to the brakes?

Tags: brakes, awd, outback, accident

My 2017 Subaru Outback was rear-ended a week back. I took it to two independent body works shop for damage estimates. Both shops were in agreement and said the following:

1. The rear body panel needs replacement.
2. The rear floor is crushed and needs replacement.
3. The right side bracket, energy absorber and impact bar need to be replaced.
4. The lift gate needs some repairs.

Both the shops also said that they don't feel anything else is damaged and that the damage is more cosmetic than functional. But, as it is customary, both the shops also said that something more may come up when the actual repairs begin.

Today, after about 6 days from the rear-end incident, when I applied brakes, I felt that my brakes slipped. This is something I never experienced prior to the incident. It felt similar to the case when EyeSight applies ABS on identifying an imminent collision, but I'm sure it was not ABS.

When the rear-ending happened, I had my car's breaks fully pressed as I had come to a complete halt at a safe distance from the car in front of me. So the car behind me hit me when my car's breaks were fully pressed.

The last useful piece of information is that the driver behind me tried to avoid the collision and tried to drive the car to right, thereby hitting the right rear end of my car. I expect that the car was at about 25-35 mph.

My questions:

1. Can a rear end collision cause damage to the breaks (or braking system)?
2. While both the shops told me that the car was safe to drive, is it possible that AWD system of the car may have been disturbed due to the hit being to right rear end?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the Eyesight system might be out of calibration after the accident.

It's under warranty, so I'd take the car to the dealer for a checkup; they're going to know more than a body shop about what might affect your ABS system.